# Sortable table not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On http://www.elitedeafpoker.com/dev/poker-players.html - I cant get the sortable table to work. I need some help to make it work.

HTML

```
<table id="myTable" class="tableData">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Rank</th>
            <th width="250">Name</th>
            <th>Earnings</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Total Earnings</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
 </table>
```

JAVASCRIPT -

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#myTable").tableData(); 
} 
);
```

jQUERY plugin - http://www.elitedeafpoker.com/dev/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js

All of the codes were referred by http://tablesorter.com/docs/ please let me know what I've missed.

Comment: IF you check your JavaScript console, you'll see the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tableData'` which suggests you've not (properly?) called the plugin.

Comment: Im showing TypeError: $(...).tablesorter is not a function @ http://www.elitedeafpoker.com/dev/poker-players.html:60 and that is the javascript shown above. Whats wrong with it? Im not expert in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the error in your browser's console: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tableData'`

The correct method that the Tablesorter plugin provides is `tablesorter`, so you want to use:

```
$("#myTable").tablesorter();
```

The website link you referenced specifically has this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
    } 
);
```

If you're using AJAX to load the rows, you need to call:

```
$("#myTable").trigger("update");
```

after they are appended.

Comment: @Christian Did you do everything I said? You're adding the rows with `$.getJSON`, which means you have to re-call the method on the table. At the end of my answer, I explained that. So inside the callback for `$.getJSON`, after the new rows are added, you have to call `$("#myTable").trigger("update");`

Comment: @Christian You're also including the jQuery library **twice**. Take one of them out. You have `1.8.3` and `latest`

Comment: Yes, thats what I did and removed one jQuery library.

Comment: @Christian No, I still see two libraries. Just use the `1.8.2` library. And sorry, I meant you have `1.8.2`, not `1.8.3`.

Comment: Im only show 1.8.2 version and it worked just fine - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I could make a suggestion about libraries, I've used tablesorter before, and eventually switched over to [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/). Excellent library, with sorting, filtering, etc. built in, and had an awesome, responsive developer, great documentation, and a great community for support.

Answer (score 0):

I would try and use [DataTables](http://datatables.net/). The library you are trying to use was last updated in 03-2008 that's almost 5 years ago. In the example The jQuery Version is 1.2. The present version of stable jQuery is 1.9+. There are many changes that are not backward compatible in the intermediate versions.

---

If you really want just table sorting. If you insist on using just javascript then you could look at this http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js . The last time 
I tried it worked fine.